# What does "Denzen/Zenzen haitenai dame" mean on a telephone message recording?

Tags: meaning, words, phrases, listening

I hear this message after dialing a phone number. I know that I cannot enter for some reason, but I don't know what the reason is. Is the message box full? Is the number not being used or misdialed? It's an automated message. Any help would be appreciated, the message seems kind of garbled. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling about a bit, I hit on [a likely thread](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1058459785).

I suspect that the actual message is something like the following.  The piece that you specifically mention is in bold.

> お掛【か】けになった電話【でんわ】は電波【でんぱ】の届【とど】かない場所【ばしょ】にあるか​**電源【でんげん】が入【はい】っていないため**​かかりません。

Breaking down the translation of the bolded portion:

> 電源【でんげん】　　が　入【はい】っていない　ため
>     power `[SUBJ]` in 　 is not 　because  →
>     because the power is not on

---

Please comment if the above does not fully address your question.

Comment: @Chocolate, thank you!  I thought that コピペ sounded a little funny...

Comment: its a great answer!